# IntelliJ bad sizes of inputs and other elements on Manjaro Cinnamon Edition

Tags: intellij-idea, cinnamon, manjaro

My IntelliJ shows UI elements incorrectly after some upgrade I think:

[image]

I use Oracle JVM 1.8, IntelliJ Ultimate Edition from AUR and vertex-maia GTK style.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the default application font. Click on File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance, check "Override default fonts by" and change the Name to "Dejavu Sans" and Size to 12.